# SUM without duplicated row with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sum

```
SELECT SUM(man+woman) AS over65, 
       a.cod, 
       a.city, 
       b.cod2 
  FROM a LEFT JOIN 
         b ON b.cod2 = a.cod 
 GROUP BY cod
```

--

```
table  a
cod    city 
28001  rome 
28001  rome 
28002  milan 
28002  milan 

table b
cod2  age man woman 
28001  65 156   220 
28001  66 250   280 
28001  67 350   483 
28002  65 556   524 
28002  66 650   683 
28002  67 450   342 

result Is:
cod    city  over65 
28001  rome    3478 
28002  milan   6410 

instead Of :   
cod     city   over65 
28001   rome     1739 
28802   milan    3205
```

What should i do for this?
thanks

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your sample data in your question as text. That way we can use it to test our solutions. See it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557) how to properly ask a good sql question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will read documentation for next post

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get rid of the duplicates in table `a`.

```
SELECT SUM(man+woman) AS over65, 
       a.cod, 
       a.city, 
       b.cod2 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cod, city
        FROM a) AS a 
  LEFT JOIN 
         b ON b.cod2 = a.cod 
 GROUP BY a.cod
```

I also wonder why table `a` has those duplicates in the first place. If `city` is always the same for a given `cod`, the data is not properly normalized.

Comment: thank you for help. Is not duplicated, I removed others columns from table a

Comment: It's still not properly normalized. If `cod` always has the same `city`, you should have that in another table where `cod` is a unique ID and `city` is a value.

Comment: Yes, in 'a' table I have unique ID and more columns, but here I removed it.
Query works fine, but is very slow for get results because I have about 20000 records in table.

Comment: An index on `(cod, city)` should help with that.